# How to remove the first and last elements from a selection?

Tags: css

I want to set margins to `li` elements :

```
 <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Administration</a>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
             <li>
                <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Indoor</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Garden</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
             <li><hr></li>
             <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
             <li><hr></li>
             <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
             <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
 </ul>
```

I want to set margin-top and margin-bottom for li elements like the "Batting Cages" element but not for the "Artificial Turf" elements. How to do that ?

Comment: `ul li:first-child` & `ul li:last-child` ??

Comment: It's not clear what rules you are trying to apply. Do you mean you want to apply the `margin-top` etc. styles to nested items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to use css rule `li:not(:first-child)` for this purpose.Here is a simple example. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ahahm08/1/)

```
.dropdown li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
{
    margin-top:10px;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I understand you need:

```
    ul li ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child),
    ul li ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) a{
        background:#64FFDA;
        width:100px;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#333;
    }
```

```css
ul li ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child),
ul li ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) a{
    background:#64FFDA;
    width:100px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Administration</a>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
             <li>
                <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Indoor</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Garden</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
             <li><hr></li>
             <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
             <li><hr></li>
             <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
             <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

---

The code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tt4mkge/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a specific id for your element. For example,

```
<li><a href="#" id="a">Artificial Turf</a></li>
```

`.class` is not advised as `id` is more unique. Each ID can only be use once.

Answer (score -1):

You can put one class on it.

Like `<a href="#" class="class name">Batting Cages</a>`

and edit it like you want

look here http://jsfiddle.net/6ahahm08/2/